# Append header value in SpringIntegration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

When I try to assign a value to url-expression is working (Below working):

```
<bean id="requestData"    class="net.model.RequestData"/>
<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="requestChannel"
        url-expression="@requestData.getCompleteUrl()" http-method-expression="@requestData.getRequestMethod()"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String" header-mapper="headerMapper"
        charset="UTF-8" reply-timeout="5000" reply-channel="responseChannel">
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

But when I try to assign a value in Header, it throws an Exception (below not working):

```
<int:gateway id="requestGateway" service-interface="net.model.RequestData"  default-request-channel="jsonTransformationChannel">
        <int:default-header name="X-MW-getId" value="@requestData.getId() />
         <int:default-header name="X-Srcsys" value="ttsim" />
        <int:default-header name="content-type" value="application/json" />
        <int:default-header name="Accept" value="application/json" />
    </int:gateway>
```

And I tried the lines below, but it didn't work:

```
<int:default-header name="X-MW-getId" expression="#requestData.id" />
```

Comment: If you get an exception you should _tell us what it is_ and give a stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one must work:

```
<int:default-header name="X-MW-getId" expression="@requestData.id" />
```

It must be definitely an `expression` attribute and if you would like to get access to the `requestData` bean from there so that should be with the `@`. The getter indeed can be used as a property accessor.

Comment: Thanks Bilan it's work now,did small mistake in channel name